# Query within the same table with combination of 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have this table and I need to create an SQL statement WHERE

I need to get ID which content are BOOK with value 05 and content is PAPER with value 'Y',

[image]

**Result must:**

```
id 
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by id`, filter the table on your conditions and check in the `HAVING` clause if both conditions are satisfied:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
WHERE (content, value) IN (('BOOK', '05'), ('PAPER', 'Y'))
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd5b4e1bc84c72a5159e5fa5c6edfee6).

Comment: @basha04 if you did not misspell PAPER with PAPPER you would see that the query works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd5b4e1bc84c72a5159e5fa5c6edfee6

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery.
You can select in one query the id-s that meet the condition and use it as a  condition
Try:

```
create table `content`(
id int(9) ,
content varchar (50),
value varchar (10) ); 

insert into content values (1,'BOOK','05'), (2,'BOOK','05'), 
(3,'BOOK','05'), (4,'BOOK','07'), (5,'BOOK','07'), (1,'PAPPER','Y'), 
(2,'PAPPER','N'), (3,'PAPPER','Y'), (4,'PAPPER','Y'), (5,'PAPPER','N');

 select id from content where content='BOOK' and value ='05' and id in (
 select distinct id from content where content='PAPPER' and value ='Y');
```

[image]

Comment: is it efficient rather than using joining to itself?